# Calling external API through jquery ajax gives me "csp:blocked " error in console

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

I am trying to call an external sample api through ajax call but gives me error as "csp:blocked" in Network of console.

Please find below code:

```
$.ajax({
url : "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
contentType: 'application/json',
type: "POST",
data : {}
success: function(result)
{

    //data - response from server
},
error: function ()
{

}
});
```

It neither hits on success or failure while debugging but gets out of both of them.I googled it but confused whether it's Content Security blocked error or cross origin ajax post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSP:

```
connect-src https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ ;
```